# Count names, divide value by counted names and solve owes statement

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a formula using Google Sheets (or Microsoft Excel) that solves following statement problem:

```
  A        B          C
1  Amount  Paid By    Beneficiaries
2  $20,00  James      Elizabeth, James, Michael
3  $4,50   Elizabeth  Elizabeth, Michael
4  $6,90   James      Michael
```

I want to calculate how much each individual owes to each other (the result I'm trying to obtain):

```
Elizabeth > Elizabeth   €2,25
Elizabeth > James       €6,67
Elizabeth > Michael     €0,00
James > Elizabeth       €0,00
James > James           €6,67
James > Michael         €0,00
Michael > Elizabeth     €2,25
Michael > James         €13,57
Michael > Michael       €0,00
```

For now, I've created two new columns, `D` and `E`, respectively called `Number` and `Amount/Number`.

For the first, `Number`, I count the column `C` names using following formula (put in cell `D2`):

```
=COUNTIF(C2;"*"&"Elizabeth"&"*") + COUNTIF(C2;"*"&"James"&"*") + COUNTIF(C2;"*"&"Michael"&"*")
```

For the second, `Amount/Number`, I divide column `A` with `D` using following formula (put in cell `E2`):

```
=A2/D2
```

So my current statement file looks following:

```
  A        B          C                          D      E
1  Amount  Paid By    Beneficiaries              Number Amount/Number
2  $20,00  James      Elizabeth, James, Michael  3      $6,67
3  $4,50   Elizabeth  Elizabeth, Michael         2      $2,25
4  $6,90   James      Michael                    1      $6,90
```

So to calculate `Elizabeth > Elizabeth`, I've used the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E; B:B; "Elizabeth"; C:C; "*"&"Elizabeth"&"*")
```

So to calculate `Elizabeth > James`, I've used the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E; B:B; "James"; C:C; "*"&"Elizabeth"&"*")
```

and so on.

My question is: is it possible to do calculate the statement without creating columns `D` (`Number`) and `E` (`Amount/Number`), using `=SUMPRODUCT()` or some similar formula? There is probably an easier way to solve my problem, your help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Google Sheets

Please try the **formula**:

`=QUERY(
  {"Paid By"\"Beneficiary"\ "Amount";
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";";
      ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula(
        rept(B2:B&";";LEN(C2:C)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C;",";""))+1));
      COUNTA(A2:A);1));";")) \
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ";1;C2:C);", ")) \
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";";
     ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula(
        rept(A2:A / 
          (LEN(C2:C)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C;",";""))+1)&";";
        LEN(C2:C)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C;",";""))+1));
     COUNTA(A2:A);1));";"))
  }; 
"select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3) group by Col1, Col2")`

The **result** is a query report:

```
Paid By        Beneficiary    sum Amount
Elizabeth      Elizabeth            2,25
Elizabeth      Michael              2,25
James          Elizabeth            6,67
James          James                6,67
James          Michael             13,57
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly! Do you know how to sum Amount (Col3) if (and only if) a column E (currently not available in my file) values (E1, E2, and so on) are blank? I've tried to add it without success in the formula provided by you. Thanks once again!

Comment: you need to replace all ranges in formula into filters: change `C2:C` into `filter(C2:C,E2:E="")`,  `B2:B` into `filter(B2:B,E2:E="")`, ,  `A2:A` into `filter(A2:A,E2:E="")`

Comment: unfortunately the filter option did not work. Do you know any alternatives? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on how you want to present the final totals of who owes who.

This will divide the Amount (Column A) by the number of Beneficiaries that are separated by commas (Column C).

```
=A2/(LEN(TRIM(C2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C2),",",""))+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is the best I could do but it does solve the issue.

First of a simplier method of counting the number of beneficiaries is:

`=A2/counta(split(C2,", "))`

This also cuts down your columns from 2 additional ones to one and however if you want to remove them it gets a bit messy. And wouldn't be very easily expanded on. If you were using this in a system which is anything but fixed then there are better and neater ways of solving this however it would require an extra column to do.

Essencially the way to do this is to include all the information which would go into a row into a single line.

To calculate `Elizabeth > Elizabeth`, I used the following formula:

`=sum(if(AND(iferror(search("Elizabeth",C2)),B2="Elizabeth"),(A2/counta(split(C2,", "))),),if(AND(iferror(search("Elizabeth",C3)),B3="Elizabeth"),(A3/counta(split(C3,", "))),), if(AND(iferror(search("Elizabeth",C4)),B4="Elizabeth"),(A4/counta(split(C4,", "))),))`

Now you can see its quite a long formula but it can be broken down into what is 3 lines:
`=if(AND(iferror(search("Elizabeth",C2)),B2="Elizabeth"),(A2/counta(split(C2,", "))),)`
`=if(AND(iferror(search("Elizabeth",C3)),B3="Elizabeth"),(A3/counta(split(C3,", "))),)`
`=if(AND(iferror(search("Elizabeth",C4)),B4="Elizabeth"),(A4/counta(split(C4,", "))),)`

The sum of these 3 lines is what gets you to `Elizabeth > Elizabeth`.