# Run query if specific column equals to zero

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to improve an [query done in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48182996/9195104) by adding an extra column called "Settlement"

```
      A        B          C                           D
1  Amount  Paid By    Beneficiaries               Settlement
2  $20,00  James      Elizabeth, James, Michael   27.07.2018
3  $4,50   Elizabeth  Elizabeth, Michael
4  $6,90   James      Michael
```

Code:

```
=QUERY(
  {"Paid By"\"Beneficiary"\ "Amount";
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";";
      ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula(
        rept(B2:B&";";LEN(C2:C)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C;",";""))+1));
      COUNTA(A2:A);1));";")) \
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ";1;C2:C);", ")) \
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";";
     ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula(
        rept(A2:A / 
          (LEN(C2:C)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C;",";""))+1)&";";
        LEN(C2:C)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C;",";""))+1));
     COUNTA(A2:A);1));";"))
  }; 
"select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3) group by Col1, Col2")
```

Now I want to avoid the sum of the values already settled - i.e., all the rows that contain any value (column D "Settlement"). In other words, I want to sum only the rows where column D is equal to zero.

Is there some way? I've already tried to replace `A2:A`, `B2:B` and `C2:C` by `FILTER(A2:A; D2:D="")`, `FILTER(B2:B; D2:D="")` and `FILTER(C2:C; D2:D="")` without success. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't gone through all of your formula, but have you tried changing the last part of the query to: `select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3) group by Col1, Col2 where Col4 =''` or `select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3) group by Col1, Col2 where Col4 is null`?

Comment: Did not work :(